# How to import open source projects into QT Creator 5.7?

Tags: qt, import, build, open-source

I've been trying to import an open-source project into Qt-Creator to read the code and to learn from it by debuging. Unfortunatly I cannot build imported projects. I found two interessting projects:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpass/files/source/

and

https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx

I imported them into Qt Creator by File-->New File or Project-->Import Project-->Import as qmake Project (Limited Functionality). Afterwards I tried to run the project and I got an error:

G:\Qt Projekte\keepassx-2.0.3\src\autotype\test\AutoTypeTest.h:23: Fehler: autotype/AutoTypePlatformPlugin.h: No such file or directory

The file is definitely existing and it's within the project. I googled it and found that there might be problem when importing Qt4 projects into Qt5. Some user recommended to insert 'Qt += widgets' into the pro-File. But it didn't solve my problem.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it? Is the way how I am importing projects into Qt Creator wrong?

Comment: In case of keepassx: I don't think you need to "import" anything, just open its CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? How do I open this file in Qt Creator so that I can run the project?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "New File or Project", you want to use "Open File or Project". Since both projects use cmake, you should be opening their topmost `CMakeLists.txt` file. I've verified that **both** of the projects open that way on OS X with Qt/Creator from macports and build successfully using either the default *CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles* CMake Generator, or *CodeBlocks - Ninja*.

Here are the things I had to do to get the builds going:

1. Add the macports binary path (`/opt/local/bin`) to the system environment in the project's build settings. That's so that `cmake` would find `ninja`. This is optional if you don't use ninja, but ninja speeds up builds by a good integer factors so it's recommended over make.
2. Add the `/opt/local/include` path to the `INCLUDE_DIR` path in QPass's `CMakeLists.txt`: otherwise it wouldn't find gcrypt's include files from macports. That wouldn't be a problem on most linux distributions, but you'd need a similar fix on windows.

Comment: But what do I have to open when I do File --> Open File or Project? I just know those standard *.pro files but they aren't there. I am using Windows and I don't know what macport is. What do you mean by CodeBlocks - Unix CMake Generator? Sorry I am totally lost and don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Peter See the edit. The cmake generator is the process used by the cmake tool to generate a build tool file. CMake is like qmake: it takes a project file, and generates a "makefile". qmake can generate output for gnu make, microsoft make (nmake/jom), XCode and Visual Studio. CMake can generate output for ninja (preferred! - very quick builds), make, and many other tools/IDEs.

Comment: I am so sorry, but it's still not working. I selected their (QPass and Keepassx) topmost CMakeLists.txt but nothing happens. After selecting QtCreator asks me how to configure the project. The only option I can chose is "Desptop Qt 5.7.0 MiniGW 32 bit". After hitting "configure project" it seems like an empty project. I got a folder that has the name of the app, e.g. Keepassx, but it's empty and everything is grey meaning not selectable. So I cannot run the project or even see any files.

Comment: You do have cmake installed and available for Qt Creator, right? Otherwise nothing will work.

Comment: I am sorry for the late answer. I had to read a bit about cmake's function as I didn't know anything. So by now cmake is installed. I tried to load and build the mentioned projects but I got following error: C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.7\Modules\FindQt4.cmake:1318: Fehler: Found unsuitable Qt version "5.7.0" from C:/Program Files (x86)/Qt Creator/5.7/mingw53_32/bin/qmake.exe, this code requires Qt 4.x CMakeLists.txt:151 (find_package). Apparently I have a wrong version of Qt. Next question would be. Could I install two versions of Qt? If yes, how to without messing up everything?

Comment: There's nothing to mess up. Qt is designed to support multiple versions installed in parallel. Qt Creator explicitly requires you to add each and every installed Qt version to it, and to choose which one is used to build a project. So not only you can install multiple Qt versions, it's very normal to do so. For reference, I usually have a couple dozen of them floating around: multiple versions, multiple configurations, multiple targets. Remember that "choosing" a Qt to build a given project is as simple as invoking the right qmake for a given Qt install. Qt Creator does that for you.